# Pagespeed insights showing unknown css file

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, w3-total-cache

When I run pagespeed insights it's showing an unknown CSS. I checked in the minify folder of my hosting server (I'm running W3 Total Cache Plugin in WordPress) but there's no file by that name. I don't see this in GtMetrix. Please check the image below:

[image]

Any ideas why it's showing this file? It's reducing my pagespeed. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: running mod pagespeed on your server by any chance?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Yes, mod pagespeed is running. Will disabling it remove the file?

Comment: yes but then you will just have other CSS file(s) to contend with, which will probably be larger, the file is your minified and combined CSS.

Comment: Thanks, @GrahamRitchie, You're right. I did content with each CSS file separately, but ultimately, I achieved the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `mod_pagespeed` activated. So if you want to take a deeper look, you can click on it and uncompress it with a "CSS BEAUTIFIER". That always helps. It is compressed by w3c, so the Name is generated.